# How to create custom interface? (Theme)

Tags: themes

I want to create my own Ubuntu 20.04 Theme but I don't know how to start. There is a lot of tutorials on how to install them but I just want to create my own. I am not advanced if it comes to programming because I know only how to make a website and some basics on how programming looks like. Even that I would be happy if I could at least change a color, size, position or remove an element. With every version it is getting worse and worse so please, can you help me? At least some examples of the files I have to edit.

There's some things I miss or hate the most.

1. No trash icon on the bottom of the dock like many years ago.
2. New device icon like Pendrive appears on the dock or desktop whenever device is connected to the computer.
3. No possibility to merge the top bar with the application bar on maximize.
4. No option to remove desktop home folder and trash. (I found 2 commands to remove them after many years of searching... without them you need to install another app just to check 2 boxes...)
5. Background folder that appears in image directory whenever you change a desktop background.

That's the things I would like to fix myself because I wait so many years and it is still not implemented as default. There are commands to disable home folder and trash from the desktop and I would like to know if there is more because I hate that I have to download gnome tweaks to do such basics that can be done without it.

Comment: Something like these examples. Some explain what they have done better than others. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2351238  I used to use gnome-panel or fallback, which was like the old gnome2, but based on gnome3. But then I found I like Kubuntu better for changes, but do not make a lot of changes.